# Application-defined or object-defined error when trying to assign font properties

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an error when I try to add the interior color & font properties to each cell; "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I've used code almost like this before and it worked fine.

```
        'Loop through cells in calendar and display audit if one exists
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A3:G11")
        For Each c In rng
            If Not IsEmpty(c) And IsNumeric(c) Then

                'Construct the file name based on user's input
                fileName = "UV_Audit-" & dirSupervisor & "-" & dirMonth & Format(c, "00") & dirYear & ".xlsm"
                If Dir(path & fileName) <> "" Then
                    With c.Offset(1, 0)
                        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c.Offset(1, 0), Address:=path & fileName, TextToDisplay:="X"
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(34, 139, 34)
                        .Font.Color = vbBlack
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next c
```

Thank you

Comment: What line throws the error? I'm guessing it's actually the `Hyperlinks.Add`.

Comment: That one works fine as long as I dont have the interior color and font properties

Comment: So then which line throws the error?

Comment: The interior.color I think...at least if I take that and the next two lines out I dont get the error

Comment: Hit `Debug` when the error occurs - what line does it highlight?

Comment: I can only hit ok or help

Comment: Normally the debug button is there but its not when it throws this error.

Comment: What is your setting under Tools>Options>General>Error Trapping?

Comment: Break on unhandled errors. Also, I added a watch to c.Offset(1,0)...it's data type shows as a variant. Shouldn't it show as an object?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an `On Error goto ...` somewhere in your previous code? If so it's best to comment that out for the time being, and see if that highlight your error line on next run.

Comment: I do and I already commented it out.

Comment: Should I just post the whole code? I only didn't because it's long.

Comment: No. Remove the `.Font.Color` and `.Font.Bold` lines. Does it still error?

Comment: It still does yes

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `With c.Offset(1, 0)` and then press F8 to step through it. This way you will know which line is giving you the error.

Comment: Okay! I figured it out. Some other code was protecting the sheet before I was changing to change the cell properties.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The sheet was protected in previous code!